# converting inline and internal styling to responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a big site that needs to be converted to a responsive layout. Problem is the previous developers have internal and inline styling all over the pages as well as tables. I've started to remove these styles and put them into one external. This is getting very time consuming and was wondering if any one has any suggestions or alternate methods for dealing with this.

here is a little of what I'm dealing with

```
<div class="header-top-scroller float-left">


   <table width="1280" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <th width="344" align="left" valign="middle" scope="col"><table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <th width="86" align="left" style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #eb3939;" scope="col">LANGUAGES:</th>
            <th width="264" align="left" scope="col">

            <table id="Table_24" width="235" height="23" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="#"><img src="images/languages_01.png" alt="" width="38" height="23" border="0" title="english" /></a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="#"><img src="images/languages_06.png" alt="" width="38" height="23" border="0" title="francais" /></a></td>   
                <td align="center"><a href="#"><img src="images/languages_05.png" alt="" width="38" height="23" border="0" title="deutsch" /></a></td>  
                <td align="center"><a href="#"><img src="images/languages_02.png" alt="" width="38" height="23" border="0" title="espanol" /></a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="#"><img src="images/languages_03.png" alt="" width="38" height="23" border="0" title="italiano" /></a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="#"><img src="images/languages_04.png" alt="" width="38" height="23" border="0" title="japanese" /></a></td>


              </tr>
            </table></th>
          </tr>
        </table></th>
        <th width="936" align="right" scope="col">
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) can be used to remove the styles, then you have to recreate the CSS by yourself (which I think is better so you can write cleaner/optimized code)

(BTW, you are showing a `table` for displaying languages, so it seems that also the html part needs a fix)